# I'm getting JSON output as just []. The same php script gives correct json data when I run it on localhost

Tags: php, json

I'm getting JSON output as just [] when I run it in localhost. But

The same php script gives correct JSON data when I run it on localhost it out puts as

```
[
   {"NAME":"RUDRESH","EMAIL":"Rudra@yahoo.com","PHONE":"1233333",  
     "PASSWORD":"abcabc","CONFIRM":"abcabc"}
]
```

localhost.php

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password="";
$db_name = "register";

//PDO is a extension which  defines a lightweight, consistent interface for     accessing databases in PHP. 
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password); 

//here prepare the query for analyzing, prepared statements use less   resources and thus run faster  
$row=$db->prepare('select * from reg');  

$row->execute();//execute the query  
$json_data=array();//create the array  
foreach($row as $rec)//foreach loop  
{  

    $json_array['NAME']=$rec['NAME'];  
    $json_array['EMAIL']=$rec['EMAIL'];  
    $json_array['PHONE']=$rec['PHONE'];  
    $json_array['PASSWORD']=$rec['PASSWORD'];
    $json_array['CONFIRM']=$rec['CONFIRM'];
    //here pushing the values in to an array  
    array_push($json_data,$json_array);    
}  

//built in PHP function to encode the data in to JSON format  
echo json_encode($json_data);  
?>
```

ftp.php

```
<?php 
$hostname = "mysql.hostinger.in";
$username = "u456344325_rudra";
$password="databasechris596";
$db_name = "u456344325_regis";

//PDO is a extension which  defines a lightweight, consistent interface for    accessing databases in PHP. 
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name", $username,$password);      
//here prepare the query for analyzing, prepared statements use less resources and thus run faster  
$row=$db->prepare('select * from reg');  

$row->execute();//execute the query  
$json_data=array();//create the array  
foreach($row as $rec)//foreach loop  
{  

    $json_array['NAME']=$rec['NAME'];  
    $json_array['EMAIL']=$rec['EMAIL'];  
    $json_array['PHONE']=$rec['PHONE'];  
    $json_array['PASSWORD']=$rec['PASSWORD'];
    $json_array['CONFIRM']=$rec['CONFIRM'];
    //here pushing the values in to an array  
    array_push($json_data,$json_array);    
}  

//built in PHP function to encode the data in to JSON format  
echo json_encode($json_data);  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is returning [] is probably because **MySQL** wasn't able to fetch any **results**, thus your **loop** did not run and hence the **empty array**.

There is no problem with your **PHP code** & the problem probably lies in your **database**.

Please make sure that your **connection strings** are correct and that your **databases have the appropriate results** to be fetched ( **your table is not empty** ).

EDIT:

What I meant by connection strings

This is the connection string for your local server correct?

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password="";
$db_name = "register";
```

And this is the connection string for your web server

```
$hostname = "mysql.hostinger.in";
$username = "u456344325_rudra";
$password="databasechris596";
$db_name = "u456344325_regis";
```

You can try executing a simple query to see if you're able to fetch **ANY** results at all from your database.

Also, you should echo out any errors that MySQL catches while running the query, it will let you know where the error is coming from.

Comment: I'm sure that database is not empty I've created the same database and the same table as it was in the LOCALHOST. and what do you mean by the connection settings?

Comment: @RudreshGowda Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you. but sorry.. database name was wrong. It is working fine now.